# How to "rewrite" a installed distro

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, dual-boot, elementary-os

I've installed elementaryOS on my PC, it's beautiful system, but in my opinion is a little heavy for my hardware (intel core 2 duo(32bit) with 3GB ram).

I've heard about mint, I was think if can I install mint from CD using windows(I have dualboot on my pc). I though in using GUI interface in windows for installation and "rewrite" elemenaryOS to installing mint, not mint based on debian,but mint based ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question it simply cannot be done, unless you want do it from a virtual machine that has access to a real, separate disk (not partition) on which you wish to install Linux Mint.  If your goal is to do the install simply and correctly then you don't want this solution.

From within the native Windows environment, Windows will not understand the commands and programs on the Linux Mint install disk.

The only, or at least by far the simplest, solution is to just boot up from the Linux Mint installation CD, then overwrite the Elementary OS installation.  Mint will wipe out the contents of that/those partition(s) so you don't have to worry about remnants of Elementary OS showing up in your new Linux Mint OS.  If you select manual partitioning, remember to select the re-format partition option for all the partitions you are using for Linux.  Be careful not to touch the Windows partitions of course.

I hope I correctly understood the goal of your question.

Side note: given your hardware limitations, I would choose a light-weight desktop environment for Mint, like Xfce.